# 2 branches off master - merge branch 1 back into master and use that code in branch 2?

Tags: git

```
master
    - branch 1
    - branch 2
```

Write a bunch of new code in branch 1, and then merge it into master.

How can I use that code in branch 2?  In my scenario, my code in branch 1 passed code review and I merge it into master and while working on branch 2 I can use and see the code that I committed in branch 1 and subsequently merged into master.

Comment: Have you considered simply merging master up into branch 2?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I see that code in branch 2, which is also branched off master?

You can check if the branch is merged into master

```
git checkout master
git branch --contains <branch>
```

Or simply use any of this commands to see if there are any differences:

```
git diff master..branch1
git log ^master branch1
```

Comment: I added a better explanation for what I am asking.  Thanks!